# How to cin again after enter ctrl + x in a while (cin<<x) loop (cin a struct)

Tags: c++, struct, istream

This is my code

```
stream& operator>>(istream& is, fraction& f) 
    {
        is >> f.numerator;
        cout << "/";
        is >> f.denominator;
    }
```

...

```
void insertFraction(fraction*& f, int& n, fraction x)
{
    int m = n + 1;
    fraction* fNew = (fraction*)realloc(f, m * sizeof(fraction));
    if (fNew != NULL)
    {
        fNew[n] = x;
        n++;
        f = fNew;
    }
}
```

...

```
void enterFraction(fraction*& f, int& n)
{
    fraction x;
    f = NULL;
    n = 0;
    int i = 1;
    cout << "Enter fraction " << i << " : \n";
    while (cin >> x)
    {
        insertFraction(f, n, x);

        i++;
        cout << "Enter fraction " << i << " or enter Ctrl + X to stop: \n";
    }
}
```

The question is, after calling the function enterFraction, I can use cin again, because of Ctrl + X, please help me to use cin again after the function enterFraction. Thank you!!

Comment: cin.clear(); does't work

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about how to make `cin` recover after an error. For that you must call

```
cin.clear();
```

Also it might be a good idea to discard any pending input that might be left over after the error. For that call

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
```

You need to `#include <limits>` for the `numeric_limits` class.

Comment: cin.clear(); doesn't help me TT, I think that was because I used cin to cin a struct...

Comment: It's possible to cin a struct. Hard to say what the real problem is without more details.